# Button to Fadeout/in using toggle

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <Script type = "text/javascript" src = "CprMdlrSrch.js"></Script>
    <link type="text/css"rel="stylesheet"href="CprMdlrSrch.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main_box">
        <p id="instructions"><strong>Please enter a part number to search.</strong></p>
        <input id="part_num_search" type="text" name="searchPhrase">
         <button id="search_button" type="button" value="button"> <strong>Search</strong></button>
        <div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#search_button").toggle(function() { 
    $("#part_num_search").fadeIn("slow");
  },
    $("#part_num_search").fadeOut("slow"); 
  });
});
```

I am just unsure what I am doing wrong. I am really just trying to out the button to make sure I am on the right track.

thanks!
-Dustin

Comment: Thank you for the comments back. i cannot get the fadeToggle to work, nor just the straight toggle, nor a straight fade. however, when I use a simple append on the button, and i created a <p></p> to hold the appends, it works just fine..very odd..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you understand how to use the toggle command. Please check out the API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

For fade toggling, try .fadeToggle(), which started becoming available since JQuery 1.4.4.
http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#search_button").click(function() {
    $("#part_num_search").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better served using http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/.

```
$("#search_button").click(function() { 
  $("#part_num_search").fadeToggle("slow");
});
```